# Calculating the number of unique BST generatable from n keys, why is my number so large

Tags: trees, probability-theory, permutations

I want to find the number of distinct BSTs I can get with 3 unique keys (i.e. 1, 2, 3)

Here's my solution:
[image]

- In case 1, we have each node have possibility, 3, 2, 1, respectively,
  so 3*2*1 = 6 ways
- In case 2, we have the same situation, the top node can be 1, 2, 3,
  three choices, second node two choices, so and so forth, so I get 6
  ways
- In case 3, it is same to case 2 and I get 6 ways

In the end I have 6 + 6 + 6 number of the beast = 18 different threes.

(Edited!)

Why does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042412/with-n-no-of-nodes-how-many-different-binary-and-binary-search-trees-possib) from Stackoverflow based on so called Catalan Number only give me 5 trees?

Comment: There are indeed five binary trees with three nodes! You missed two zig-zag trees on three levels. It is also important to note that for a **search tree** there is only *one way* to put the three keys in each tree. Your answer will be five.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You overcounted some of the trees and left out two other possibilities. In your Case 1, for example, there is only one possible BST of that form, namely the one with 2 in the root, 1 in the left subtree and 3 in the right subtree (the leftmost tree below). Remember that you have to maintain the binary search tree condition: a node with value $k$ must have each of the values in its left subtree less than or equal to $k$ and each of the values in the right subtree must be greater than or equal to $k$. As a consequence, a BST with node values $\{1, 2, \dotsc,n\}$ must have [inorder traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Inorder_traversal) equal to $\langle1, 2, \dotsc,n\rangle$. When $n=3$, then, we'll have these five BSTS:

[image]

Comment: Deep and interesting answer

Answer (score 1):

The catalan number $C_n$ is equal to the number of binary trees with $n$ *internal* nodes, where every node has degree $0$ or $2$. It does *not* consider the keys in the nodes, it looks only at the structure.

There is an error in your calculation, namely that the result should be 6+6+6, not 6*6*6.

Comment: Sorry what is the difference between internal nodes? Are these the guys who are not roots or leaves?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.